# If $a,b,c$ are complex roots of $X^3 -X +1$ then we have $a^3=a-1$, $b^3=b-1$ and $c^3=c-1$, why is this true?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am doing an exercise from a book, and at some point the correction states that as $a,b,c$ are complex roots of $X^3 -X +1$, then we have this:
$$a^3 = a-1 $$
$$b^3 = b-1 $$
$$c^3 = c-1 $$
But I fail to understand why. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Being a root of a polynomial means when you plug it into the polynomial, you get zero.

Comment: If $u$ is a root of $X-4=0$, then $u=4$. You get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a, b, c,$ are roots of this , it means $a,b,c$, when put on the place of $x$ will give value $0$

Which is same as $$ a^3-a+1=0$$ or $$a^3=a-1$$ same argument holds for $b$& $c$

Comment: That was so obvious, how didn't I see it! Thank you very much!